# How to create a correct URL according to nested routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, nested-routes

I am trying to create some nested routes in a react project using the `useRoutes` hook. But I am struggling to make the `URL` show as I want.

The example struture project is this one:

```
- public
- src
  - Components
    - Header.js
    - MaterialsDetails.js
    - Materials.js
    - TitleDetails.js
    - Titles.js
- App.js
- index.js
- routes.js
```

I have create the routes in `routes.js` like this:

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Titles from "./Components/Titles";
import TitleDetails from "./Components/TitleDetails";
import Materials from "./Components/Materials";
import MaterialDetails from "./Components/MaterialDetails";
import Header from "./Components/Header";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Header />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/titles",
        element: <Outlet />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <Titles />
          },
          { path: ":id", element: <TitleDetails /> }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "/materials",
        element: <Outlet />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <Materials />
          },
          { path: ":id", element: <MaterialDetails /> }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
export default routes;
```

Then I have the `HeaderLayout.js` that will be shown in every page:

```
import React from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function HeaderLayout() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Header Layout</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

In `titles.js` I have a list of titles where each title has its details when clicking on it:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Titles() {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>Titles</h3>
      <p>
        <Link to="1">Title example 1</Link>
      </p>
      <p>
        <Link to="2">Title example 2</Link>
      </p>
      <p>
        <Link to="3">Title example 3</Link>
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Then in `TitleDetails.js` apart of having the title detail I have a link to go to the related materials. So when I click I will go to the list of materials:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function TitleDetails() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Details of title {id}</h1>
      Related materials: <Link to="/materials">Materials</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

And finally in `Materials.js` I have the same concept as `Titles.js`. A list of materials that when I click on one I will go to `MaterialDetails.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Materials() {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>Materials</h3>
      <p>
        <Link to="1">Material example 1</Link>
      </p>
      <p>
        <Link to="2">Material example 2</Link>
      </p>
      <p>
        <Link to="3">Material example 3</Link>
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

The question is how can I modify `routes.js` to obtain, for example, that URL: `http://localhost:3000/titles/1/materials/3` instead of going to `http://localhost:3000/materials` when I amb in `http://localhost:3000/titles/1`?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of react-router-dom are you using? Also how do you use `routes`?

Comment: Hey! I am using `react-router v6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

I changed `routes.js` to:

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Titles from "./Components/Titles";
import TitleDetails from "./Components/TitleDetails";
import Materials from "./Components/Materials";
import MaterialDetails from "./Components/MaterialDetails";
import HeaderLayout from "./Components/HeaderLayout";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HeaderLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/titles",
        element: <Outlet />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <Titles />
          },
          { path: ":id", element: <TitleDetails /> },
          { path: ":id/materials", element: <Materials /> },
          { path: ":id/materials/:idMaterial", element: <MaterialDetails /> }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
export default routes;
```

and then in TitleDetails.js I removed the `/` of `/materials`:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function TitleDetails() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Details of title {id}</h1>
      Related materials: <Link to="materials">Materials</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```